# How to decrease the height of Input Text Field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Well, I am designing something that needs a compact layout. The design that I had made in Figma is what I want but the result I am getting while doing so, that's a bit different. I am not able to attain that level of compactness that I need.

What I designed in Figma:

[image: Designed]

What I coded in Flutter:

[image: Coded]

You see, there's an extra amount of space present above the text. I want to remove that text any how. So could anyone please help me in cutting out the extra padding that I don't need.
Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class CardHolderTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardHolderTextField({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 175,
      height: 55,
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
        maxLength: 30,
        minLines: 1,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
        style: GoogleFonts.mavenPro(
          fontSize: 10,
          color: Colors.white,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          counter: Text(""),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          focusColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried a lot, playing with the size of the container, but that doesn't work, instead pops out a -ve error.
This happened when I tried to decrease the size of the container to 40:

[image]

TextAlignVertical.top() also fails to solve the problem when container size is reduced to 40.

What I guess is it's not the problem of container, it's the problem of Text Field.
Anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using column as parent of TextFiled?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Column as parent

Comment: Would you like to stick with the font size 10?

Comment: Yeah, but I can make an increase of about 1-2 pixels, not more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` size depends on parent size. In this case, you can tweak the value according to your UI and providing `contentPadding` from `TextFiled>decoration:`. How-ever, there could be space-problem depending on `fontSize`+ etc. I prefer using `stack`.

I removed `Container` from your `CardHolderTextField`

```
class CardHolderTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardHolderTextField({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
      maxLength: 30,
      minLines: 1,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
      style: GoogleFonts.mavenPro(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 12,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        // filled: true,
        focusColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use with `Stack`

```
  SizedBox(
                height: 80,
                width: 175,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      child: Text(
                        "card holder".toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: CardHolderTextField(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

In this case, the result will be

[image]

If you consider removing bottom line `border: InputBorder.none` and use `Divider` on `Stack`, you will get more control over UI.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
It just worked like butter!
Just one more question, why Text Field depends upon the Parent? I did the same thing in Column and the same issue had occur but not with Stack. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Stack Size also depend on parent and there is no limitation with boundary(overflow). There could be other explanations, but I think it this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(              
  width: 100.0,
  child: TextField(                                 
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40.0,
      height: 2.0,
      color: Colors.black                  
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: please provide some information about how your code improves the answer to the above question.

Comment: I can't afford to increase the size of font by 4 folds. Also, cursor size increases when increasing the height of the font and making the fontSize to 10.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].